# Inline optimization for recursive functions, with the help of a where clause (in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, optimization, inline, ghc

### Prelude

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658438/can-ghc-really-never-inline-map-scanl-foldr-etc) This post says:

> "For a self-recursive function, the loop breaker can
> only be the function itself, so an INLINE pragma is always ignored," according to the GHC manual

2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260763/15292025) This answer describes a method of optimization via in-lining by GHC.
3. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366987/15292025) This (unrelated) post explains compilers are free to reject explicit inline suggestions anyway. Or perhaps passing the `-O2` flag to the compiler achieves the same effect as the OPTIMIZED VERSION shown below?

### Example code

(as seen in Link 2)

```
--PRE-OPTIMIZED VERSION--
func :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
func f [] = []
func f [x] = [x]
func f (x:s:xs) = x:(f s):(func f xs)

----OPTIMIZED VERSION----
func :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
func f = loop
  where
    loop []  = []
    loop [x] = [x]
    loop (x:s:xs) = x : f s : loop xs 

------Eg-USAGE----------
> mapToEverySecond (*2) [1..10]
[1,4,3,8,5,12,7,16,9,20]
```

---

### **Question**

To quote @amalloy's doubts in the [comments of Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260763/15292025), surely

> `f` is "still *implicitly* passed around just as much [as explicitly
> passing f in the PRE-OPTIMIZED VERSION] by the closure-creating
> machinery"  ?

As an aside, I am reading up on fusion techniques, an alternative approach as described in Link 1, although I am not trying to seek the fastest implementation possible in lieu of idiomatic styles.

Merely curious as to **whether/how "where-definition" trick** seen in the OPTIMIZED VERSION works (should the compiler decide to inline such a function).

Extra links are most welcome!

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `\f -> \list -> case list of { …func… }` while the second is `let { loop = \list -> case list of { …loop… } } in (\f -> loop)`. The [full laziness](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--ffull-laziness) optimisation in GHC will convert the former to the latter. In general this increases sharing (of `f` here) and provides opportunities for inlining; [`INLINE`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#inline-and-noinline-pragmas) pragmas work quite differently from C++’s `inline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather bad example because there's very little if anything to be gained by inlining this particular code. But similar patterns slow up all the time in situations where it matters. The big idea is that in the "optimized" `func`, if I write

```
func myFun
```

GHC can inline `func` and get

```
let
  loop []  = []
  loop [x] = [x]
  loop (x:s:xs) = x : myFun s : loop xs 
in loop
```

In this context, that's not meaningfully better, but if the result of `myFun` were demanded strictly, then it would replace a call to an arbitrary address with a call to a known address, which is faster. Furthermore, if `myFun` were used in an "interesting" context (where something is known about the argument passed to it or what's done with its result), then GHC would likely inline `myFun` to take advantage of that.

Comment: Fascinating, so would the programmer have to pass an explicit flag to demand myFun strictly? Also, would you please give examples where inlining can really make a significant impact, possibly expanding on the cases when GHC knows about the argument - presumably more so than just their (concrete) types?